# How to get all orders by orderId in magento

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

I want all orders from a particular orderId.

```
<?php 
namespace Racom\Chatbotapi\Model;

use Racom\Chatbotapi\Api\ChatbotapiInterface;

class Chatbotapi implements ChatbotapiInterface
{
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
    }



    /**
     * Returns the Orders list.
     *
     * @api
     * @param Integer $orderId order Id.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function getOrder($orderId) 
    {
        $productCollection = $this->order->load($orderId);

        $a = $productCollection->getItems();

        $v = json_encode($a);

        return $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin you want all order items

**Change**

```
$a = $productCollection->getItems();
```

**to**

```
$a = $productCollection->getAllItems();
```